# How do I quantify a mix of SiO2 (amorphous), silicon (amorphous, polycrystal), graphite (dust) in a solid sample?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy

I collected solid samples from a plugged tube-side of a heat exchanger. These deposits include compounds such as hexachlorodisilane, hexachlorodisiloxane, pentachlorodisilane, graphite dust and amorphous/polycrystalline silicon dust. In the process of collection, the sample has been exposed to moisture, and hence the disilanes should have hydrolyzed to silica/HCl, siloxanes, etc. and the graphite and silicon should remain unaltered.

How do I go about quantifying each component? I am expecting this will be a multi-step analysis with separation/extraction followed by a combination of analytical techniques.

Comment: It is always beneficial to state what instruments you have access to.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend sending a sample to a company or lab that can run a Raman spectrum, an ATR infrared spectrum and an SEM-EDAX. The companies will probably run samples for free if you can convince them you want to buy an instrument[or are very nice]. Careful preparation of standards should give reasonable quantitative data from at least one of the methods for each component. I do recommend that much more care be exercised in sample collection and preservation.